# Assigning a variable's address to another variable

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a way to assign a pointer value (not the dereferenced value, but the actual address of the variable) to another variable? For instance

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   unsigned int *p;
   size_t q;
   q = (size_t) p;
   printf("p = %x q = %x\n", p, q)
}
```

does not seem to do the job... I get 0,0 for each of these...

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `p`.  You could get any value printed.  What were you expecting as output?

Comment: @JohnZwinck p is a pointer variable on the stack it should have an address, he is trying to print the address.

Comment: @MosheRabaev: OP is printing the address stored in `p`.  But that address was never assigned, so it could print anything.  It's printing arbitrary garbage, and the fact that it printed 0 is just "luck."

Comment: Thanks guys! as soon as p is initialized, I am getting the correct behavior. I added - int r; p = &r; and things worked normally.

Comment: You might consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963269/can-someone-explain-how-pointer-to-pointer-works/23964156#23964156) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print an **address** in c, you must send the address of variable `&variable`.

```c
int main(void) {
   int i = 0;

   printf("The address of the variable is : %p", &i);
}
```